# Check if token works with endpoint - Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, nodes

Unsure how to go about checking the auth token and how it has been set up. First, I'm calling a token endpoint on login on the front end - api/token - the response I get back is the token I use on the rest of the endpoints for this app as a header on the front end. The call - api/token - is making a call to another server side project in a different language. Anyways, I get back the token from this call. How do I check if the token is correct on the node side on each call?

Here's simple middleware I've added but it's not checking to see if the token that was given is the correct one. Is that normal to even check if the token is correct? Or just to check if a token is present?

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
        if(!req.headers.authorization){
            return res.status(403).json({ error: 'No credentials sent!'});
        }
        next();
    })
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is that normal to even check if the token is correct? Or just to check if a token is present?

You need to check for both the "presence" and "validity" of the token

If you check only for the presence, you might allow invalid tokens that you haven't issued from the
server

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    // this will allow if the authorizaton is set to '1' or 'some random string'
    return res.status(403).json({
      error: 'No credentials sent!'
    });
  }

  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send({
    result: 'hello world'
  });
});
```

Here, clearly `123` is an invalid token. But still the application allows it

> curl -H 'Authorization:123' http://localhost:3000

**Response**

> {"result":"hello world"}

We can fix this by validating the token received using a [`jwt-simple`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple) or any similar packages

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let jwt = require('jwt-simple');
  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      error: 'No credentials sent!'
    });
  }


  try { 
    let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    var decoded = jwt.decode(token, 'your secret here');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err ', err.stack);
    return res.status(403).json({
      error: 'invalid token'
    });
  }

  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).send({
    result: 'hello world'
  });
});
```

**Response**

> {"error":"invalid token"}

Comment: When I send the token from the front end, I'm getting back an invalid token error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0. ---- authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVFQetc...'

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm updated the answer for stripping bearer off the token. Can you check now

Comment: now I'm getting this error - Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line